# Explain stationary distribution in CTMC in simple words

Tags: stationarity, markov-process

How to explain the stationary distribution and limiting distribution in the continuous-time Markov chain to non-stats people? Like what does the probability vector implies?

For example, if the stationary distribution = (0.3,0.2,0.5) for states 1 to 3, does that refer to the probability of an individual in state 1 after a long time being 0.3? Or 30% of people in the sample will be in state 1 in the long run?